# Reload entire page except the User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

My application has one master page and 5 child page to load inside it.

**Contents of Master Page**:
1. UserControl (Drop Down)
2. 5 Main Tabs (Child Page loads for every Main Tab Click).

Initially when application loads, all the data is loaded for Drop Down and one of the child page .

so whenever a click on one of the main tab link (its href),so whole page gets reloaded and data will be loaded again for all the controls of the page.

so , i don't want to load the data for my drop down again and again on every Main Tab Click.

As i am working on legacy application every thing is coded, i can't use Update panel for this as a solution because it requires lot of code change.

so i am looking for a solution to keep my Drop Down Data static across all the tabs, even if it refreshes for every tab click.

Answer (score 0):

Why not hide the information in a div and display only each div when its clicked?

...this will keep the links static and only navigate between the pages.

Put all the code on one page:

CSS:

```
#content > div {
    display: none;
}

#content > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- All static Page data here -->
<ul>
<!-- Menu Links -->
<li><a href="#div1">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#div2">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#div3">Page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#divX">Page X</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="content">
<div id="div1">

<!-- All Page 1 Data Here -->

</div>

<div id="div2">

<!-- All Page 2 Data Here -->

</div>

<div id="div3">

<!-- All Page 3 Data Here -->

</div>

<div id="divX">

<!-- All Page X Data Here -->

</div>    
</div> <!-- Closing the content div tag -->
```

Let me know how you get on :)

Good Luck

Comment: hi josh, right now all my child pages are getting data dynamically through different web services and there are lot of java script files associated to each and every child page. if i follows the above approach and place all my JS files(all child page's) and child pages into single master page the application performance might come down.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, please let me know if you have any other ideas or approach.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you need to use a common place to store your data , you may use session

fill the session with data on app start -- now on every page refresh / page load keep a check if session has data don't bind the drop down (in user control).